# With PHP/MYSQL need to INSERT to a Table With a IN Condition

Tags: php, mysql, insert, conditional-statements

I am working on a product search in PHP/MySQL. When a User search for a Product (Can search for more than one product.), it should take the data from Table A and Inserts in Table B. The user can search for more than one product. I have problem in query. It is slow, and it is not getting all the products related to product search.

My SQL query is below:

```
$arr = explode(",",$values["prod_cat"]);

for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
$strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO TABLE B (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, 
sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) (SELECT sup_id, sup_name, sup_prod_name, sup_contactperson, 
sup_email, ".$values["tender_id"]." FROM TABLE A WHERE sup_prod_name IN ('".$arr[$i]."') 
GROUP BY sup_name)";
```

Is it good to use 'IN' Condition or 'LIKE' condition. Is this query the best way to achieve the result?

Comment: why you are using loop and mysql in at sam timee. $arr[$i] will return single value from your array.

Comment: Iam a novice in php/mysql. Can you please suggest me a better solution with query.

Comment: In is fine. But Why have a GROUP BY clause???

Comment: Iam using a Group by clause because, i dont want to repeat the Suppliers of that particular products. Which means product A will be supplied by Supplier A, product B will also be supplied by Supplier A. In this case i need to just show one Supplier A. If it repeats also its fine.Not very particular that i need to use Group by Clause there.

Comment: Anyone who can guide me?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this instead:

```
$strSQLInsert = "
  INSERT INTO TABLE B 
  (
      sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, sup_contactperson_email, tender_id
  )
  SELECT 
     sup_id, sup_name, sup_prod_name, sup_contactperson, sup_email, ".$values["tender_id"]." 
  FROM 
     TABLE A 
  WHERE sup_prod_name IN ('".$values["prod_cat"]."') 
  GROUP BY sup_name";
```

Since `$values["prod_cat"]` is already a comma separated string you can insert it right into your sql string.

Comment: Are you sure? sup_produ_name is string and you put whole string in one single quote. is this work??

Comment: Let me just check it this works, but i had a problem with single quot previousy.

Comment: Actually $values["prod_cat"] is not comma seperated string. For that i used $arr = explode(",",$values["prod_cat"]);. Am i correct?

Comment: No the above query doesnt work. It is just taking the first string of search and inserting.

Comment: `explode(",", $string);` means take the string $string and separate it into an array on every occurrence of `,`. So if you're telling me $values["prod_cat"] is not a comma separated string than `explode(",", $values["prod_cat"] );` will not work in creating an array.